# How to protect memory and cpu resource to one group of process on centos

Tags: linux, docker

In my situation, I have over 30 processes running on a single server through Docker. I have two critical Docker containers that I need to protect from potential memory constraints caused by other processes, including the operating system and boot-up programs. How can I guarantee that these essential 2 Docker containers won't be adversely affected?

I have used cgroups, but I don't know how to protect from potential memory constraints caused by other processes,including the operating system and boot-up programs.

Comment: Docker Compose does provide some ability here, but for more sophisticated coordination you probably need something like Kubernetes that gives you a way more robust priority system.

Comment: It sounds like you might need hard realtime. That's a job for specialized embedded systems kernels, not Docker _or_ Kubernetes. For that matter, the market leader for decades was VxWorks, not anything based on Linux at all. (They may still be the leader today; it's just not a field I work in anymore).

Comment: My program is a wind turbine scada system, and all programs run on one server in B/S mode. I don't want to increase the cost.